# C# Send IList with socket

Tags: c#

I can send a simple text with socket to my client. But how can I send array, IList or Class to my client. I want to send this format

```
Product= car, Price = 1

Product= pencil, Price = 2
```

And after I want to show this collection on my `gridview` like this

```
Product       Price

Car              1

pencil           2
```

Thanks your advise

Best Regards

Comment: What socket? Are you using TcpClient, WebClient, raw socket...

Answer (score 3):

You need to decide on a serialization format, basically. For example:

- "Standard" .NET XML serialization
- "Standard" .NET binary serialization
- Your own XML format
- Protocol Buffers
- Thrift
- JSON

There are lots of options... you need to decide on one, based on your requirements (e.g. versioning your data structures, compactness, multi-platform vs just .NET etc).

Ultimately, it's all bytes - you need to decide how to represent your data in those bytes.

Comment: *cough* Clever product placement :)

Comment: Firstly thanks for your answer. can u see any demos or example Standard" .NET binary serialization? thanks again